# Erro de divisão entre colunas com Subquery SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, porcentagem

Estou usando postgreSQL

Tenho uma query que quando executo uma divisão entre as colunas (soma_bairro / Soma_cidade) ele retorna sempre 1, deveria retornar o valor descrito no campo e não a quantidade de contagem da linha, segue exemplo.

Acredito que erro esta aqui :

```
(COUNT(distinct neighborhood) / COUNT(distinct tbl.city)) as percentual
```

Como faço pra ela entender o valor do campo e não da conta?

```
SELECT 

city, 
neighborhood, 
count(neighborhood) as Soma_bairros,

(select count(city) FROM tb_listings WHERE city = tbl.city) as Soma_cidade ,

(COUNT(distinct neighborhood) / COUNT(distinct tbl.city)) as percentual

FROM tb_listings tbl

GROUP BY city, neighborhood 

ORDER BY city, neighborhood DESC
Resultado atual:
```

Percentual retorna 100 e não 33 %

[image: Resultado atual]

Teria que classificar campo como INT ?

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi bem o que você queria na query, é pra calcular o percentual de bairros por cidade, ou o percentual total da tabela?

Notei também que a lógica da sua query está incorreta, porque você ta dividindo a quantidade distinta de bairros pela quantidade distinta de cidade, como o distinct vai trazer so 1 vez cada valor, então o resultado sempre dará 1, porque 1/1 = 1.

Por falta de informações do objetivo da query, eu fiz uns testes e consegui, com a query abaixo, calcular o percentual de bairros por cidade:

```
SELECT  
CITY, 
NEIGHBORHOOD, 
COUNT(NEIGHBORHOOD) AS SOMA_BAIRROS,
(SELECT COUNT(CITY) FROM TB_LISTINGS WHERE CITY = TBL.CITY) AS SOMA_CIDADE ,
CAST(CAST(COUNT(CITY) AS NUMERIC(4,0)) / CAST(COUNT(NEIGHBORHOOD) OVER (PARTITION BY CITY) AS NUMERIC(4,0)) * 100 AS INT) PERCENTUAL
FROM TB_LISTINGS TBL
GROUP BY CITY, NEIGHBORHOOD
ORDER BY CITY, NEIGHBORHOOD DESC;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: o cast vai servir para formatar o numero em inteiro, para não ficar o valor quebrado no resultado do calculo, caso não queira, pode seguir da forma abaixo:

```
SELECT  
CITY, 
NEIGHBORHOOD, 
COUNT(NEIGHBORHOOD) AS SOMA_BAIRROS,
(SELECT COUNT(CITY) FROM TB_LISTINGS WHERE CITY = TBL.CITY) AS SOMA_CIDADE ,
(COUNT(CITY) / SUM(COUNT(NEIGHBORHOOD)) OVER (PARTITION BY CITY)  * 100) PERCENTUAL 
FROM TB_LISTINGS TBL
GROUP BY CITY, NEIGHBORHOOD 
ORDER BY CITY, NEIGHBORHOOD DESC;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue explicação de como funciona o **over partition by** https://www.devmedia.com.br/funcoes-analiticas-em-oracle/3707

Bons estudos!